# No visible @interface for 'xxx' declares the selector

Tags: ios

I tried change of view but I have the netx error: **No visible @interface for 'primera_vista' declares the selector 'presentModalViewController:animated:completion'**

**My code:**

```
-(IBAction)goSecondView:(id)sender
{
    segunda_vista *segundaVista = [[segunda_vista alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    segundaVista.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
    segundaVista.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController: segundaVista animated: YES completion:nil];
}
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: [self presentViewController: segundaVista animated:YES completion:nil]; should be used

Answer (score 0):

There's no `presentModalViewController:animated:completion` method.

Instead it's `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Use it like this:

```
[self presentViewController: segundaVista animated: YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: "The `presentModalViewController:animated:completion` method doesn't exist anymore" - did it ever? :) `presentModalViewController:animated:` did.

Comment: Sorry, I only get onto the iOS train with iOS6 when it was already deprecated, so I don't know the exact signature since I never used it :)